# WooCommerce - Free Shipping if shipping class is true AND quantity is over some number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My cart needs to have free shipping if a specific product with shipping class is there and the quantity of that product is over 8. Doesn't matter if it has another product on the cart. The shipping fee will be free.

Because what I have right now looks for the shipping class (which is correct) but counts the quantity of the ENTIRE cart. Not that specific product with shipping class on the cart. How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'show_hide_free_shipping', 10, 2);
function show_hide_free_shipping($available_shipping_methods, $package){
    $minimum_number_of_item = 12; //Give here minumum number of items to allow freeshipping
    $shop_country = 'AU'; //Give here the country code where the store located

    $free_shipping  =   false;
    global $woocommerce;
    $customer_country = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country();

    $item_count = 0;
    foreach (WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item) {
        $item_count += $item['quantity'];
    }

    if( $item_count >= $minimum_number_of_item && $customer_country ==  $shop_country ){
        $free_shipping  =   true;
    }

    if($free_shipping){
        foreach($available_shipping_methods as $shipping_method =>  $method){
            if( strpos( $shipping_method, 'free_shipping' ) === false ) {
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$shipping_method]);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        foreach($available_shipping_methods as $shipping_method =>  $method){
            if( strpos( $shipping_method, 'free_shipping' ) !== false ) {
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$shipping_method]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Got from below link.
You can use it with some tweaks.

https://www.xadapter.com/showhide-free-shipping-based-item-count-domestic-shipment/

https://www.xadapter.com/hide-shipping-methods-shipping-classes-exist-not-exist-cart/